# Button Event not getting fired in tableviewCell

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I m adding a tableviewCell in my nib where i m adding an UIButton in one the cell .the problem is the IBAction of the button is not getting fired.i m able to click the button could u guys help out.will be so greatful

Comment: Did you link the IBAction to the UIButton by right clicking on your fileOwner object in the nib?

Comment: yup its done perfectly..its like this inside a tableView ..i m adding tableview cell where the button is placed

Comment: are you adding both the UITableViewCell and UIButton through nib?

Comment: If you are adding a UITableViewCell on top of the button, how will the touches go to the button?

Comment: which one is on top in the view hierarchy?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15752/discussion-between-crypticcoder-and-user578386)

Answer (score 1):

another way to do it... create a uibutton and add it to the cell where ever you need it

inside **- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** use switch to check the table row

```
switch (indexPath.row)
```

if the case matches then use this

```
UIButton *yourButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(your_method_to_handle_button_clicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
yourButton.frame=CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>);

[cell addSubview:yourButton];
```

Comment: inside the table view adding a button is works fine..its little complicated where inside the tableview.i m adding a tableview cell where the butto is placed